# Is Random Forest accuracy related to the number of partitions in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, random-forest

In Spark, is there any relationship between the accuracy of the Random Forest classifier and the number of partitions that the training data occupied?

For example, we store the training data on 10 partitions and train a RandomForest classifier (RF1). then we repartition the training data on 20 partitions and train the second RandomForest classifier (RF2).
Is there a technical difference between RF1 and RF2?

Comment: did you try yourself?

Comment: @thebluephantom yes. I tried it and it sounds me that there is not a meaningful difference between the accuracies. However, I did not conduct any statistical test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems logical but in reality sort of obvious:

- If you re-partition, you alter the distribution of the data every time in general. The same data over N or N + M partitions when training data is taken typically will not yield the same results.

  `val Array(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))`
- Obtaining your training and test, validation data is then, with the same parameters, a different set of outcomes.

So, you are working with different training data and will likely get a slightly different result as a consequence.

So the short answer is yes and no. There is an indirect relationship and possibly not as you thought when you asked the question. One cannot argue that more partitions means better accuracy.

I ran this a number of times:

```
...
val data = data0.repartition(N) // N varying
...
val Array(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3),seed=333)
...
```

I noted that with a move from lower to higher number of partitions I got a varying accuracy, sometimes higher, sometimes not.